# spring data CustomBackendIdConverter: implement fromRequestId method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have the same problem like it discussed in the [implementation of toRequestId() in the CustomBackendIdConverter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801575/customizing-hateoas-link-generation-for-entities-with-composite-ids)

The method works. But how can I implement **fromRequestId()** (another direction)? I get the error:

```
"No converter found capable of converting from type String to type CustomerId"
```

if I call

```
http://localhost:8080/demo/customers/1_1
```

If I debug I only get the combination of String and Customer (in the **fromRequestId()**), and not of String and CustomerId. Actually I should call my repository in the method to get my Customer from the String **1_1**, shouldn't? (I understand, I should split it before in **id** and **startVersion**).

How does it work? I cannot simply @Autowire my repository in the class.

The addition of dependencies alone, as it described in another answer, doesn't help. Probably, some additional configuration should be done.

Thanks in advance.